# QGIS Time Manager animation does not run

Tags: qgis, timemanager

I'm encountering some problems with Time Manager that after adding layer to Time Manger settings the animation doesn't run. Nether the play button or trough slider. I'm following steps of the video (https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=nHrFOPf1UGw&t=283s). What should be the field type for changing attribute?

Sample data:

```
x       y       aika                haitta10

550144  7116401 01-01-2001 00:00:00 0
550144  7116401 02-01-2001 00:00:00 2
550144  7116401 03-01-2001 00:00:00 4
```

[image]

QGIS 2.14.10, Time Manager 2.4, Windows 7

Answer (score 6):

Before playing the animation, make sure the **power button** is switched on (turns up green).

- Before

  [image: Before]
- After

  [image: After]